# Python 3.12 issue when npm install command

Tags: python, node-modules

when i run the npm install command then below error will show. not able to run the npm install command

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Users\AnilKale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: C:\Users\AnilKale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

Node version 18.17.0

I tried with installing and add python path in environment variable
refer the below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiQaO.png)

Comment: Why is this an issue with Python 3.12?